# .net WPF IValueConverter Constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, ivalueconverter

Simple question:

Why do I have to have a `constructor` for a `IValueConverter`?

I'm not asking, why do I have to have an `empty constructor`, I'm asking why do I have to have one at all?

If I have:

```
public class PauseButtonValueConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
  //public PauseButtonValueConverter() //<- Uncomment this and the error is fixed
  //{
  //}

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Then, my `VS2012` gives me the compile-time error: `No constructor for type 'PauseButtonValueConverter' has 0 parameters.`

If I add the `constructor`, the error is fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're deriving from MarkupExtension, the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.markupextension.aspx) for which is protected. In this case, the compiler doesn't auto-generate a default constructor. You must add it yourself.

In most cases, you shouldn't need to derive from MarkupExtension when creating a value converter. I'm assuming you have a reason for this, but if not, just remove the base class.

Comment: @MichaelGunter- This makes sense... I didn't think about the fact that the default constructor wouldn't be generated BECAUSE of my base class.